# date() expects parameter 2 to be integer, float given

Tags: php

I got the following timestamp long value from database 147836340000 and I want to convert it on data and time. I have tried to use the following:

```
$timestamp=147836340000;
print_r(date('m/d/Y H:i:s', $timestamp));
```

But unfortunately I am getting the following error:

> date() expects parameter 2 to be integer, float given

Please advice on what I need to do.

Comment: what date is that timestamp supposed to for? If its November 5th, it might be off by 2 `0`'s, which is a weird amount. Usually its 3 or 6 `0`s when I see this error.

Comment: This works fine in php 5.6.17. What version of php are you running?

Comment: Yeah, it's return `09/30/6654 20:00:00`

Comment: You're using a pretty old version of PHP. The newer versions accept that LONG value just fine, earlier ones would accept only an INT

Comment: you're outside the representable range of an `int` in 32bit php, so that number was converted to a float. Most likely that's a javascript timestamp, in milliseconds, which means you ahve to `/1000` to convert to seconds.

Comment: May be you are using not int type for the column in db.

Comment: hello, thanks for the replies. Im getting the Jan 01 1970 for the above code I mentioned. I am using php 7.

Comment: It all depends on whether you are running on a 32-bit or 64-bit machine, operating system and PHP version. Should be fine with 64-bit.

Comment: For what it's worth, the unix timestamp `1478363400` (with two trailing zeros) gives a date of around Nov 5, 2016. http://www.4webhelp.net/us/timestamp.php?action=stamp&stamp=1478363400

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably JS timestamp, so you need to divide it by 1000. But in your example, the date looks off by one extra `0` at the end. It should be `1478363400000` according to JS specs.

Your version:

```
$timestamp=147836340000;
print_r(date('m/d/Y H:i:s', $timestamp));
> 09/30/6654 18:00:00
```

Try this one ([Online Demo](https://3v4l.org/Gqunt)):

```
$timestamp=(int) 147836340000 / 1000;
echo "Wrong: " . date('m/d/Y H:i:s', $timestamp) . PHP_EOL;

$timestamp=(int) 1478363400000 / 1000;
echo "Corrected: " . date('m/d/Y H:i:s', $timestamp) . PHP_EOL;

> Wrong: 09/08/1974 02:39:00
> Corrected: 11/05/2016 17:30:00
```

More details can be found here: [Timestamp between Javascript and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593759/timestamp-between-javascript-and-php)

Comment: I am getting this value from your example sir : 01/21/1970 23:04:11

Comment: @momori14 what version of PHP you use? Check this online demo: https://3v4l.org/qdcD9

Comment: I am using PHP7

Comment: Also depends on hardware and operating system - if everything is 64-bit you are good to go, if anything is 32-bit you have a problem.

Comment: It looks like this timestamp needs to be divided by 100?  That gives us Nov 5, 2016, a few weeks after the original post.