# PHP timestamp to Date returning bizarre date

Tags: php, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I was trying to transform a timestamp:

```php
$timestamp = 1565806556964168;
```

To a DateTime value format: **"Y-m-d H:i:s"** but it is giving this value:

```
49620404-07-14 23:22:48
```

I've tried using like this:

```php
$timestamp = 1565806556964168;
$time = new DateTime("@$timestamp");

// $time->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));

echo $time->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That timestamp looks a little large, did it come from a iPhone?

Comment: It's from a mobile device, yes.

Comment: A PHP timestamp for NOW is `1566419028`

Comment: It's about 6 digits too long. By cutting off the last 6 digits to make it **1565806556**, I get **2019-08-14 14:15:56**

Comment: That is actually the correct date for the given timestamp. Also, what are you trying to accomplish with `"@$timestamp"`? Why the `@` symbol?

Comment: I've used an example that I've found @Mike

Comment: Divide `$timestamp` by 1,000,000

Comment: It will always work? And why is that?

Comment: I forget, had this issue with mobile device generated timestamps. It may be a javascript thing, if I remember correctly

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593759/timestamp-between-javascript-and-php